# uniform_real_distribution<float> all possible values generation

Tags: c++, random, floating-point, precision, uniform-distribution

I am currently working on importance sampling, and for testing purposes I need to be able to generate all possible values that `uniform_real_distribution<float>` may generate for the interval [0,1] (yes it is closed from the right too). My idea was to generate integer numbers which I can then convert to floating point numbers. From the tests I made it seems that there is a perfect bijection between uniform single-precision floats in [0,1] and integers in [0,2^24] (I am a bit bothered by the fact that it is not [0,2^24-1] and I am still trying to figure out why, my best guess is that 0 is simply special for floats and 1 to 2^24 all result in floats that have the same exponent). My question is whether the floats generated this way are exactly the floats that can be generated from `uniform_real_distribution<float>`. You can find my integer <-> float tests below:

```
void floatIntegerBitsBijectionTest()
{
    uint32 two24 = 1 << 24;
    bool bij24Bits = true;
    float delta = float(1.0) / float(two24);
    float prev = float(0) / float(two24);
    for (uint32 i = 1; i <= two24; ++i)
    {
        float uintMap = float(i) / float(two24);
        if (uintMap - prev != delta || uint32(uintMap*float(two24)) != i)
        {
            std::cout << "No bijection exists between uniform floats in [0,1] and integers in [0,2^24].\n";
            bij24Bits = false;
            break;
        }
        prev = uintMap;
    }
    if(bij24Bits) std::cout << "A bijection exists between uniform floats in [0,1] and integers in [0,2^24].\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    uint32 two25 = 1 << 25;
    bool bij25Bits = true;
    delta = float(1.0) / float(two25);
    prev = float(0) / float(two25);
    for (uint32 i = 1; i <= two25; ++i)
    {
        float uintMap = float(i) / float(two25);
        if (uintMap - prev != delta || uint32(uintMap*float(two25)) != i)
        {
            std::cout << "No bijection exists between uniform floats in [0,1] and integers in [0,2^25].\n";
            if (i == ((1 << 24) + 1)) std::cout << "The first non-uniformly distributed float corresponds to the integer 2^24+1.\n";

            bij25Bits = false;
            break;
        }
        prev = uintMap;
    }
    if (bij25Bits) std::cout << "A bijection exists between uniform floats in [0,1] and integers in [0,2^25].\n";
    std::cout << "\n";


    bool bij25BitsS = true;
    delta = 1.0f / float(two24);
    prev = float(-two24) / float(two24);
    for (int i = -two24+1; i <= two24; ++i)
    {
        float uintMap = float(i) / float(two24);
        if (uintMap - prev != delta || int(uintMap*float(two24)) != i)
        {
            std::cout << i << " " << uintMap - prev << " " << delta << "\n";
            std::cout << "No bijection exists between uniform floats in [-1,1] and integers in [-2^24,2^24].\n";
            bij25BitsS = false;
            break;
        }
        prev = uintMap;
    }
    if (bij25BitsS) std::cout << "A bijection exists between uniform floats in [-1,1] and integers in [-2^24,2^24].\n";
}
```

EDIT:

Somewhat relevant:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/uniformly-distributed-secure-floating-point-numbers-in-0-1

http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/random_real.c

https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/29ducz/obtaining_uniform_random_floats_is_trickier_than/

https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/

EDIT 2:

I finally managed to figure out what `uniform_real_distribution<float>` does at least when used with the `mt19937` engine when used with its default template arguments (I am talking about the implementation that comes with VS2017). Sadly, it simply generates a random integer number in [0,2^32-1] casts it to float and then divides it by 2^32. Needless to say this produces non-uniformly distributed floating point numbers. I am guessing, however, that this works for most practical purposes unless one is working close to the precision of the deltas between generated numbers.

Comment: (a) The properties of `float` are implementation-dependent. (b) In IEEE 754 32-bit floating-point, there are about 2\*\*30 representable values in [0, 1], so there is no bijection with the integers in [0, 2\*\*24]. There is a bijection with a subset of the representable values in [0, 1]. (c) No, not all representable values in (0, 1] have the same exponent. They have exponents ranging from −126 to 0, along with the special cases that are the subnormals. (d) The specification of `uniform_real_distribution` looks inadequate to determine how it deals with floating-point granularity.

Comment: Of course, given as many representable floating-point values as integers in [0, 2\*\*24], there is necessarily a bijection. But, more particularly, for each integer *n* in [0, 2\*\*24], *n* / 2\*\*24 is a value representable in IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point.

Comment: (b), (d) Take notice of the "uniform" part, while there are many floating point numbers in [0,1] only a subset of those are uniformly distributed, since `uniform_real_distribution` is supposed to produce uniform values, I do not expect it would produce any output outside the uniform floats in [0,1]. I just want to make sure that this subset is exactly `n/2^24`, where n is in [0,2^24].

Comment: Consider a simplified floating-point format that had representable values 0, 1/32, 1/16, 1/8, 1/4, and 1/2. How would `uniform_real_distribution(0, 1/2)` work? First, it is obviously impossible for it to return any values in (1/8, 1/4), so it generates numbers in that interval with zero probability, which contradicts the requirement that it generate numbers with probability equal to that for the interval (0, 1/8). Second, if that is resolved in some way, there is a question of how to attempts to apportion the probabilities among these values with differing spacing.

Comment: Have you tested it? If you get samples from `uniform_real_distribution` and multiply them by 2\*\*24, is the result always an integer?

Comment: I am specifically asking here because I do not want to wait for uniform_real_distribution to converge, and what's more I am uncertain when it will converge, so I am unsure when I should stop it (to know when it has converged I need to know the subset of these floats)... Basically I need to know what subset of floats `uniform_real_distribution<float>` may produce when called for the interval [0,1].

Comment: I just tested it on macOS; it does not generally produce values that are *n* / 2\*\*24 for some integer *n* in [0, 2\*\*24]. I do not believe `uniform_real_distribution` is sufficiently well specified in the C++ standard to determine what its behavior is in the floating-point details. It is likely intended as a rough approximation at a gross level. If an application’s needs are so fine that the differences between representable floating-point values matter, then the behavior of `uniform_real_distribution` likely breaks down.

Comment: FYI, the representable numbers in IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point are those that equal *M* • 2\*\**e* for some integers *M* and *e* such that | *M* | < 2\*\*24 and −149 < *e* <  104. So the representable values in [0, 1] are those for which 0 ≤ *M* ≤ 2\*\*24 and −149 < *e* ≤ −24. (Note that some values are repeated in this characterization. For example, 1/4 is both (2\*\*23)•2\*\*−25 and (2\*\*22)•2\*\*−24.)

Comment: Don't you mean `[0..1<<24 -1]` ?

Comment: @JiveDadson Check my tests above, I also found it strange that the bijection works between [0,2^24] and [0,1]. I was making assumptions based off the available bits for the mantissa, but it seems some of my assumptions missed the mark.

Comment: In IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, the representable values from 1 to 2 are regularly spaced at distances of 2\*\*−23. Assuming your implementation uses IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point for `float` and `uniform_real_distribution` is well implemented, if you define `x` with `std::uniform_real_distribution<float> x(1, 2);`, then `x(generator)-1` will generate values in [0, 1) with regular spacing. That is, every value will equal *n* / 2\*\*23 for some integer *n* in [0, 2\*\*23), and the values should appear with uniform distribution.

Comment: I just wrote a small test, that seems to work at least for the first 1000 numbers generated by uniform_real_distribution. You can formulate it as an answer so that I can select it as solved. Btw, what reference did you use to look that up (I want to add it to my collection)?

Comment: I did not look it up; I am just familiar with the IEEE-754 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume the C++ implementation uses the IEEE-754 32-bit basic binary format for `float`. In this format, the representable floating-point values in [1, 2] are regularly spaced, at a distance of 2<sup>−23</sup>.

Define `x` with:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> x(1, 2);
```

Then, assuming `uniform_real_distribution` is well implemented and a proper engine is used, `x(engine) - 1` will generate values equal to *n* / 2<sup>23</sup> for integers *n* in [0, 2<sup>23</sup>), with uniform distribution.

## Notes

I have misgivings about the specification of `uniform_real_distribution` in C++. It is defined in terms of real arithmetic. The requirement that it return values with constant probability density requires a continuous set of numbers, which the floating-point format does not provide. Additionally, I am not sure how implementations will handle endpoints.

Since the distribution has been forced to be discrete, one might as well use `uniform_int_distribution` and multiply the samples by 2<sup>−23</sup> (available as `numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()`). The has the benefit of clarifying the endpoints and easily supporting intervals of [0, 1) or [0, 1], as desired.

Even if the C++ standard does not use IEEE-754, representable values in [1, 2] should be evenly spaced, due to the description in the C++ standard of floating-point values as represented by some number of digits in a certain base, multiplied by the base raised to some power. For the power zero, the values from 1 to 2 would be spaced according to the value of the least significant digit in the format. As above, that distance would be `numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()`.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> The C++ standard uses legacy term “mantissa,” but the preferred term is “significand.”

Comment: How does `std::numeric_limits<float>::radix` figure into the calculation, if at all, for float with radix != 2?

Comment: @Eric: Please note that while `uniform_int_distribution` provides numbers on a closed range, `uniform_real_distribution` gives numbers on a half-open range.

Comment: @NicolBolas: See notes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Comment: Can you confirm that my assumption that the largest uniformly distributed set of 32 bit IEEE-754 floats in [2^j, 2^(j+1)] (j in [1,23]) is exactly the set { 2^j + n/2^(23-j) | n in [0,2^(23-j)] } is correct? Also for [0,1] it should be { n/2^24 | n in [0,2^24] }. So if one wants to generate uniform float numbers in [a,b], one needs to consider in which interval b falls, and based on that choose the corresponding set. I have provided an example related to my question: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bda63c95419b060

Comment: @JiveDadson: The C standard defines floating-point numbers with a summation (C 2011 [N1570] 5.2.4.2.2 2) that essentially says a floating-point value is some power of *b* multiplied by ± . *f1* *f2* *f3* *f4* … *fp* in base *b*, where *b* is the radix, and *f1* *etc.* are digits in base *b*, and *p* is the number of digits. So, when the power is 1, and the sign is positive, the value is *f1* . *f2* *f3* *f4* … *fp* in base *b*. Then the next value is determined by a change of 1 in the low digit, so that distance is *b* \*\* (1-*p*). `numeric_limits<Type>::epsilon()` should equal that.

Comment: (C describes that model of floating-point numbers in discussing `<float.h>`, and the C++ standard includes this C header.)

Comment: @lightxbulb: In fact, the representable values in [2^j, 2^(j+1)] are exactly { 2^j + n/2^(23-j) | n in [0, 2^(23-j)] }, except when you reach the high or low end of the format, so it is the largest set of anything in that interval. This is also true for [½, 1], which shows why for [0, 1] it is { n/2^24 | n in [0, 2^24] }—one is simply taking the union of { ½ + n/2^24 | n in [0, 2^23] } with { n/2^24 | n in [0, 2^23] }. The former is all the representable values in [½, 1], and the latter is the a subset of the representable values in [0, ½].

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I was just testing this. So basically, there is a bijection between all floats in [2^j, 2^(j+1)] (which are evenly spaced with a delta of 2^(j-24)) and [0,2^23] ? Now I am not sure what the possible interval for j is however - I have been trying to figure that out by writing more test cases. However all of this implies that if one wants to generate random floats in [a,b] from integers, let `c = |a|<=|b|? b : a;`, then he can simply take `j = ceil(log2(c));`, and have a spacing between generated floats of 2^(j-24).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I believe n should be in [0,2^23] and not [0,2^(23-j)].

Comment: @lightxbulb: Yes, n should be in [0, 2^23].

Answer (score 1):

You could force the issue. Roll your own random float generator.

EDIT: I just discovered `std::generate_canonical<float>()`, which does the same thing, but does not depend on the magic number 24. It works that out from `std::numerical_limits<float>::digits`, etc...

```
#include <random>

static const unsigned long big = 1 << 24;
static std::default_random_engine re;
static std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long> uint(0, big - 1);

float rand_float() {
    return uint(re) / static_cast<float>(big);
}
```

Comment: Sadly I do not have the option of rolling my own float generator, since I am working with code that uses uniform_real_distribution that I shouldn't really modify.

Comment: Btw your code generates floats in [0,1), not [0,1]. If the you remove the -1, it should work correctly for [0,1].

Comment: That was intentional. Canonical uniform floats are conventionally defined on [0,1).  Things just work out better that way.  In this case, there are 2^24 distinct values.

Comment: Added the remark just in case somebody copy-pastes it for [0,1], since my question was referring to the [0,1] interval. I agree however that even `uniform_real_distribution` defines the [a,b) interval with (a,b) as constructor arguments, unless you make use of std::nextafter as a workaround.

Comment: Come to think of it, you better use `big = 1<<23` for IEEE floats.  I reckon any good implementation of `uniform_real_distribution<float>` is going to do that behind the curtains.

Comment: big = 1<<24 works just fine, at least judging by my test code.  However 1<<23 is what I was looking for at least in the interval [1,2) - see Eric's last comment under my question. From the tests I have ran it seems that the values generated in [1,2) by `uniform_real_distribution<float>` are the values `1.0f +float(n)/float(1<<23)`, n in [0,2^23). I am not entirely certain that this is true for all values, since I need to find the implementation for this.

Comment: You can work out what the biggest correct `big` is by using `std::numeric_limits<float>`, `::digits` and `::radix`. Now I'm again thinking that 24 is correct for IEEE float. My brains hurt.

Comment: Floating-point numbers have different density depending on the interval. big = 1<<24 works for a bijection between uniform floats in [0,1] (note there are a lot more floats in [0,1] than the uniformly distributed ones) and integers in [0,2^24]. big = 1<<23 works for a bijection between [1,2) and [0,2^23), etc.

Comment: Yeah, I found the generate_canonical also. std::numerical_limits<float>::digits is simply the number of bits for the significand, so exactly 24 for 32bit IEEE-754 floats. In MSVC's implementation radix is not used. Looking at the code, for [0,1] all 24 bits are used, the larger (_Gxmax - _Gxmin) gets, the less actual random bits we get. Considering this, and the fact that the random number construction is done in real numbers I think I can safely assume that the distribution isn't ideally uniform for every interval.